# Java- How to find min and max values in sequence of integers?

Tags: java, max, min

I'm fairly new to coding and I'm trying to find the minimum and maximum of a sequence of integers by using Math.min and Math.max methods. I think I have most things figured out, but when I test it the minimum is -2147483648 and the maximum is 2147483647. How can I change that?
Here's the code:

```
/**
 * A class to find largest and smallest values of a sequence.
 **/
public class DataSet
{
  private int smallest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  private int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  /**
   * Adds in integer to sequence.
   * @param x the integer added
   */
  public void addValue(int x)
   {
    smallest = Math.min(smallest, x);
    largest = Math.max(largest, x);
   }
  /**
   * Returns the smallest value.
   * @return the smallest value
   */
  public int getSmallest() 
   {
    return smallest;
   }
  /**
   * Returns the largest value.
   * @return the largest value
   */
  public int getLargest()
    {
      return largest;
    }
}
```

Here's the tester:

```
/**
 * A class to test the DataSet class.
 */
public class DataSetTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DataSet myData = new DataSet();
        myData.addValue(11);
        myData.addValue(4);
        myData.addValue(6);
        myData.addValue(9);
        System.out.println("Smallest: " + myData.getSmallest());
        System.out.println("Expected: 4");
        System.out.println("Largest: " + myData.getLargest());
        System.out.println("Expected: 11");
    }
}
```

Comment: For posterity's sake, in real life if you wanted the max and min elements from a collection, then using a `SortedSet` like `TreeSet` is a good way to go.

Comment: The problem asked for Math.max and Math.min, but I'll keep that in mind for the future, thanks.

Comment: use                                                                                                         int highest=Math.MIN_VALUE;
int lowest=Math.MAX_VALUE;

Answer (score 7):

Swap the initial conditions for `smallest` and `largest`. Change

```
private int smallest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
private int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

to

```
private int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Because no `int` value is smaller than `MIN_VALUE` (or larger than `MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: @Tricia This is where using your debugger should have helped you find this bug.